# How to collect outputs of vector-valued function into a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I have a function `f1` that takes a number `k` as input and returns 3 numbers `k, k+1, k+2`. I would like to ask how to concatenate these results into a dataframe for `k` from 1 to 10. In this way, the line `k` corresponds to the output `f1(k)`.

```
f1 <- function(k){
  return (c(k, k+1, k+2))
}

f1(1)
f1(2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to `Vectorize` the function 'f1', pass the values 1 to 10, returns a `matrix`, and then convert it to `data.frame` with `as.data.frame`

```
as.data.frame(Vectorize(f1)(1:10))
```

If it needs to be vertical, then `t`ranspose the output and apply `as.data.frame`

```
as.data.frame(t(Vectorize(f1)(1:10)))
```

-output

```
#    V1 V2 V3
#1   1  2  3
#2   2  3  4
#3   3  4  5
#4   4  5  6
#5   5  6  7
#6   6  7  8
#7   7  8  9
#8   8  9 10
#9   9 10 11
#10 10 11 12
```

---

Or we can use `outer`

```
as.data.frame(outer(1:10, 0:2, `+`))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(1:10,f1)))
```

Output:

```
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(1:10,f1)))
   V1 V2 V3
1   1  2  3
2   2  3  4
3   3  4  5
4   4  5  6
5   5  6  7
6   6  7  8
7   7  8  9
8   8  9 10
9   9 10 11
10 10 11 12
```